# You are given $B,G,H,J$ bases for a real linear space $X$ and the change of basis transition matrices. What is the dimension of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

[image]

I'm not sure how I should go about this question, so I can't really give any other information. All I know is that dimension is the number of vectors in the basis set $X$.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the $i$th column in a basis transformation matrix is the $i$th basis element coordinated in the other basis. 
Since the matrices have $3$ columns, there were $3$ elements in any of the given bases.

Comment: what should i do with the information about the transitions?

Comment: Ignore that. Aren't there more parts of the exercise? Maybe a next (perhaps lost) page?

Comment: If not, I can give you one: Find the transition matrix for $\mathcal H\leftarrow\mathcal G$.

Comment: nope, thats it. So im not sure i get this, is the dimension just equal to 3 then?

Comment: Yes, sure, the dimension of $X$ must be $3$. It might be also a typo or an accidentally deleted line from the source TeX file while preparing the exercise book. I also think they wanted to also give exercises about finding any other transition matrix.